# Testing a Singleton

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, singleton

I've created a singleton which in the constructor goes like this:

```
public static class MyCertificate
{
    private readonly static X509Certificate2 _singletonInstance = new X509Certificate2();

    static MyCertificate()
    {
        if(_singletonInstance == null)
            _singletonInstance = GetMyCertificateFromDatabase();
    }

    public static X509Certificate2 MyX509Certificate
    {
        get { return _singletonInstance; }
    }
...
}
```

the MyX509Certificate property returns _sigletonInstance.

What I need to do though is debug the methods being called such as GetMyCertificateFromDatabase().  So in an.aspx.cs I have this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InsertCertificate();
    }

    private static void InsertCertificate()
    {
        X509Certificate2 certificate;

        certificate =  MyCerfiticate.MyX509Certificate;

    }
```

I am not quite sure how to step through so that I can step through the methods being called that help to set that singleton.  It just steps to the property then returns when I debug the InsertCertificate()

Comment: This is not the right way to make a singleton, to begin with.

Comment: Ok, humor me then.  I've looked it up.  Tell me what I did wrong...first time because I do not see it.  All I want back is the Certificate instance after being set in the constructor.  The only thing I wonder about is having both a new keyword after the private field AND a call to get an instance using that GetMyCertificateFromDatabase method.  Probably shouldn't have both going on right?

Comment: Is there something that says you must instantiate it via private field vs. in the constructor?

Comment: See http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/singleton.html

Comment: yes I've seen that.  The problem was in my example above I should not be initializing that private field.

Comment: The manner in which you edited it is going to keep GetMyCertificateFromDatabase() from ever being called in the static constructor because _singletonInstance is never null.  Replace "new X509Certificate2()" with "GetMyCertificateFromDatabase()" and remove the static constructor altogether.

Comment: yea, true.  But somewhere I still have to check for == null before creating a new instance.

Comment: No, you don't.  It's never null when your code looks at since it's assigned statically in a field initializer ONCE.  Unless, of course, GetMyCertificateFromDatabase() returns null for some reason.

Comment: @coffeeaddict: What Jesse Slicer said.

Comment: Jesse, I was thinking in terms of: 1) first time it's referenced it calls GetMyCertificateFromDatabase().  Now it has an instance.  So there is one and only one MyCertificate foating around in the heap.  Then some other code somewhere else calls and tries to use the singleton class MyCertificate again down the line in code somewhere.  The backing field then calls GetMyCertificateFromDatabase() again?  but that would mean GetMyCertificateFromDatabase() would be creating 2 objects in memory and I'd have 2 instances of MyCertificate right?

Comment: I guess I still don't get why even if a static field can only have one instance..why you still don't need to check if it's null before it calls the GetMyCertificateFromDatabase() again when some code down the line tries to use this singleton again for the second time.

Comment: @coffeeaddict: Because static fields are only initialized once per class.  You can certainly assign to them later via other methods if you feel like it, but that line of code executes once.  No 2 objects.  One.  That's the meaning and implementation of the Singleton instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are using visual studio.  In visual studio go to Tools->Options->Debugging and uncheck the box that says step over properties and operators

Edit:  I just noticed that you do the following:

```
private readonly static X509Certificate2 _singletonInstance = new X509Certificate2();
```

That'll prevent your _singletonInstance from ever being null when you check it.

Comment: It doesn't even hit my constructor even if I put a break point on the if null check

Comment: Double check that you didn't accidentally set your project to release instead of debug.  You'll never hit any break points if you are building release dlls

Comment: Either don't set it at all (leave it null) so that the static constructor can detect the condition or have this static field declaration call GetMyCertificateFromDatabase().  Doing both will ensure GetMyCertificateFromDatabase() never gets called at all.

Answer (score 2):

_singletonInstance is initialized before MyCertificate() is called. There, you check if _singletonInstance is null and since it is not, GetMyCertificateFromDatabase is not called.

Comment: this being a static constructor & static Singleton class, I still need to somewhere check for null don't I?

Comment: just set it to null in initialization and in the MyX509Certificate property getter check if it is null, if so create the instance with GetMyCertificateFromDatabase, then return the field.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try to set up a breakpoint in MysCertificate static constructor? This should help.

Answer (score 0):

in the module window, does the module that has your singleton in appear in the list?  Does it have symbols loaded.  If not, manually load symbols for it and then you should be able to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class MyCertificate
{
    private readonly static X509Certificate2 _singletonInstance = GetMyCertificateFromDatabase();

    public static X509Certificate2 MyX509Certificate
    {
        get { return _singletonInstance; }
    }
...
}
```

set your breakpoint on the field with its initialization.

Comment: ah since it's static no need to check to see if it's null first before assigning

Comment: or is that check for null still valid?  You have to have an instance of the singleton somewhere

Comment: Unless GetMyCertificate() returns a null on the first call, then no, there is no need for a check for null.  It is your one and only instance.  If it COULD return a null on the first call, then you'll need to check in your static property and re-call GetMyCertificate().